# python 5 d matrix writing in nc file

Tags: python

I recently migrated from MATLAB to Python.

The problem is I am reading a **U variable** from a `.nc` file which has a shape of `(2920 x 2 x 292 X 326)=[(365x8) x level x lat x lon]`  where 365 are days and 8 times data in a day.

I want to make them monthly mean files with 8 levels which I have done so my matrix is now `U_temp=[12x8x2x292x326]`, where 12 months, 8 times, lat, and long data is prepared.

So I wanted to print each yearly `U_temp` as a `.nc` file which I am unable to do.

I tried many methods but unable to do so. Since I am calculating a new dimension of months and times I am incorporating that also.

Many thanks in advance...

This is my code:

```
import netCDF4 as nc
import numpy as np
import copy
filename = 'monthly_U_'+str(i)+'.nc'
ds = nc.Dataset(filename,'w',format='NETCDF4')
#ds = nc.Dataset('new3.nc','w',format='NETCDF4') 

#print(ncfile)

### creating diminsion
month_dim= ds.createDimension('month', 12)
time_dim= ds.createDimension('time', 8)
level_dim= ds.createDimension('level', 2)
lat_dim = ds.createDimension('lat', 292)
lon_dim = ds.createDimension('lon', 326)

#### creating varaiables

month = ds.createVariable('month','f4', ('month',))
time= ds.createVariable('time','f4', ('time',))
level= ds.createVariable('level','f4', ('level',))
lat= ds.createVariable('lat','f4', ('lat',))
lon= ds.createVariable('lon','f4', ('lon',))
U=ds.createVariable('U','f4', ('month','time','level','lat','lon',))
U.units='m/s'

#### puting value

month[:]= np.arange(start=0, stop=12, step=1)
time[:]= np.arange(start=0, stop=24, step=3)
lat[:] =  np.linspace(5, 40, num=nlat)
lon[:] =  np.linspace(60, 99, num=nlon)
level[:] = [975, 1000]
U[:,:,:,:,:] = U[:,:,:,:,:]

wrtnc(file,U)

ds.close()
```

***The correct modified code is this***

```
filename = 'monthly_U_'+str(i)+'.nc'
ds = Dataset(filename,'w',format='NETCDF4')
#ds = nc.Dataset('new3.nc','w',format='NETCDF4') 

#print(ncfile)

### creating diminsion
month_dim= ds.createDimension('month', 12)
time_dim= ds.createDimension('time', 8)
level_dim= ds.createDimension('level', 2)
lat_dim = ds.createDimension('lat', 292)
lon_dim = ds.createDimension('lon', 326)

#### creating varaiables

month = ds.createVariable('month','f4', ('month',))
time= ds.createVariable('time','f4', ('time',))
level= ds.createVariable('level','f4', ('level',))
lat= ds.createVariable('lat','f4', ('lat',))
lon= ds.createVariable('lon','f4', ('lon',))
Umean = ds.createVariable('Umean','f4',('month','time','level','lat','lon',))
Umean.units='m/s'

#### puting value

month[:]= np.linspace(1, 12, 12)
time[:]= np.linspace(0, 21, 8)
lat[:] =  np.linspace(5, 40, num=nlat)
lon[:] =  np.linspace(60, 99, num=nlon)
level[:] = [975, 1000]

Umean[:,:,:,:,:] = U[:,:,:,:,:]
#wrtnc(file,U)

ds.close()
del Umean
del U
del u
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem happens here `U[:,:,:,:] = U[:,:,:,:]`, the right part of the equation should be a matrix with valules those you want to put into U like `[975, 1000]` in `level[:] = [975, 1000]`. And check `wrtnc(file,U)`, there is no variable `file` in your code below.